# Call a list value into a table on a SharePoint page

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, html-table, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to call a value from a List into a cell in a table on a different SharePoint page. The table is composed using html, and I think that is where I'm having trouble trying to connect the dots. The code for the particular cell is:

```
 <td style="background-color:Black; color:White; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border- 
style:inset">Days</td>
```

The value in the List (CurrentTimeFrame) is a numeric value from the column "days" which I need displayed before the words 'Business Days' in the cell. I have about 17 cells that I will need to set up, but if I can figure out one, I can work on the rest. I am basically a complete newbie with html/js, but I do have some training in CPP, so to say I'm struggling is putting it mildly.

I'm thinking this would be a code snippet that I can insert in the for that cell:

```
 <td style="background-color:Black; color:White; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border- 
style:inset"><div id="shippingDays"></div>&nbspDays</td>
```

Obviously this doesn't work. But I really don't know/understand why. I have also looked up REST API, as I know that is probably my best bet, but I'm just not grasping it (how to make it all work).

SharePoint 2013, 
 List name: CurrentTimeFrame, 
 Row 0 name/title column: first value in column is domesticshipping, 
 Column name: Days(internal name of c3t9)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Editing to add:

This is the set up for the table that I have. Ignore my bad PSing skills. I needed to take out the fields for privacy reasons. But the list values will need to be inserted before each black cells 'business days'. It isn't a table that just lists everything straight down a line.

[image: HTML table on separate SharePoint page]

There are three different SharePoint pages involved. 1) The SP list, 2) a SP page that has text entry to update the numerical values in the list, 3) a SP page that holds the HTML table that will have the list values inserted into the various cells.

I did try to use the following code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var listName="CurrentTimeFrame";
    getListItems(listName); 
}); 
function getListItems(listName){
    var url =  _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + 
"/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('"+listName+"')/items?$orderby=c3t9";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data.d.results,function(i,item){
                var trHtml='<tr align="middle"><td 
align="left">'+item.title+'</td>';                    
                trHtml+='<td style="background-color:Black; color:White; text- 
align:center; font-weight:bold; border- 
style:inset">'+item.c3t9+'&nbspDays</td></tr>';            
                $("#myHTMLTable>tbody").append(trHtml);
            });
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));  
        }
    });
```

But it displayed this on the SharePoint page as:

[image]

This is the SP list (also note the internal column name for 'days' is 'c3t9'):

[image]

And finally, html code for the table (not entire table, but the remaining cells are all formatted the same):

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" align="center" border="0">


     <thead>
          <tr style="height:70px">
          <th rowspan="2" colspan="9" style="width:30%; background- 
   color:#015A78; color:White; text-align:center; font-size:35pt; font- 
   weight:bold; border-width:thick; border-style:inset"> Current Time 
Frames<br> 
    <span style="color:Red; font-size:25pt;">*Secondary Header Message*</span> 
    </th>
          </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>

           <tr>
          <td colspan="9" style="font-size:5pt">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="height:40px">
          <td colspan="4" style="width:30%; background-color:#015A78; 
color:White; text-align:left; font-size:20pt; font-weight:bold; border- 
width:thick; border-style:inset">Shipping</td>
          <td></td>
          <td colspan="4" style="width:30%; background-color:#015A78; 
color:White; text-align:left; font-size:20pt; font-weight:bold; border- 
width:thick; border-style:inset">Scanning</td>
          </tr>


          <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="width:30%; background-color:#015A78; 
color:White; text-align:center; font-size:20pt; font-weight:bold; border- 
width:thick; border-style:inset">Domestic</td>
          <td style="background-color:Black; color:White; text-align:center; 
font-weight:bold; border-style:inset">Business Days</td>
          <td></td>

          <td colspan="3" style="width:30%; background-color:#015A78; 
color:White; text-align:center; font-size:20pt; font-weight:bold; border- 
width:thick; border-style:inset">Overall</td>

          <td style="background-color:Black; color:White; text-align:center; 
font-weight:bold; border-style:inset">Business Days</td>
          </tr>

     </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the code into a script editor web part in site page to achieve it.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var listName="CurrentTimeFrame";
    getListItems(listName); 
}); 
function getListItems(listName){
    var url =  _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('"+listName+"')/items?$orderby=shipping asc";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data.d.results,function(i,item){
                var trHtml='<tr align="middle"><td align="left">'+item.shipping+'</td>';                    
                trHtml+='<td style="background-color:Black; color:White; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border-style:inset">'+item.days+'&nbspDays</td></tr>';            
                $("#myHTMLTable>tbody").append(trHtml);
            });
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));  
        }
    });
}
</script>
<table id="myHTMLTable" border='1' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1'>
<thead><tr><th>Shipping</th><th>Days</th></tr></thead>
<tbody/>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you SO much! I did try to add this, but I couldn't get it to work. I'm wondering if it is because of the way I have my table set up on the other SharePoint page. I edited the original question to show a picture of the way the table is set up.

Comment: Basically at this point I'm lost. I alter a little, then alter more code, then I think I messed it completely up. Funny, not funny.

Comment: I suggest you check the columns internal names, and provide the html table code for further research.

Comment: I updated the information under the section "Editing to Add." The internal column name of 'days' is 'c3t9'. I did try to manipulate the code to get the title column names to show but still no luck. But I also need to figure out how to get it into the html table on a different SP page.